# Fit multivariate gaussian distribution to a given dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning

I need to fit multivariate gaussian distribution i.e obtain mean vector and covariance matrix of the nearest multivariate gaussian for a given dataset of audio features in python. The audio features (MFCC coefficients) are a N X 13 matrix where N is around 4K. Can someone please outline the packages and technique to fit the gaussian for this data in python?

Answer (score 35):

Use the numpy package. [numpy.mean](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) and [numpy.cov](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html) will give you the Gaussian parameter estimates. Assuming that you have 13 attributes and `N` is the number of observations, you will need to set `rowvar=0` when calling `numpy.cov` for your `N x 13` matrix (or pass the transpose of your matrix as the function argument).

If your data are in numpy array `data`:

```
mean = np.mean(data, axis=0)
cov = np.cov(data, rowvar=0)
```