# Is there a way to fit a 3D Gaussian distribution or a Gaussian mixture distribution to a vector?

Tags: python, numpy, 3d, distribution, gaussian

I have a vector of data points that seems to represent a 3D Gaussian distribution or a Gaussian mixture distribution. Is there a way to fit a 3D Gaussian distribution or a Gaussian mixture distribution to this matrix, and if yes, do there exist libraries to do that (e.g. in Python)?

The question seems related to the following one, but I would like to fit a 3D Gaussian to it:
[Fit multivariate gaussian distribution to a given dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27230824/fit-multivariate-gaussian-distribution-to-a-given-dataset)

The targeted end results would look like this (a single distribution or a mixture):
[image]

For example, very much simplified, my data vector (from which the Gaussian (mixture) distribution should be learned) looks like this:

```
[[0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,1,1,1,1,0], [0,1,2,2,1,0], [1,2,3,3,2,1], [0,1,2,2,1,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

Comment: Looks like you want something of the type Z = gaussian1(x, y) + gaussian2(x,y) etc? Because those are just regular 2d gaussians then...

Comment: I think so, but I would like to learn these functions from the data (i.e., a matrix that represents this distribution).

Comment: So you have (x,y,z) sets which define points on these planes? Or are these plots representing an envelope of the data?

Comment: I don't have all points on the plane, so it's more an envelope of the data.

Answer (score 0):

I can give an answer if you know the number of Gaussians. Your vector gives the Z values at a grid of X, Y points. You can make X and Y vectors:

```
import numpy as np
num_x, num_y = np.shape(z)
xx = np.outer(np.ones(num_x), np.arange(num_y))
yy = np.outer(np.arange(num_x), np.ones(num_y))
```

Then follow any routine fitting procedure, for instance [2D Gaussian Fit for intensities at certain coordinates in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539933/2d-gaussian-fit-for-intensities-at-certain-coordinates-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

There is so-called Gaussian Mixture Models (GMM), with lots of literature behind it. And there is python code to do sampling, parameters estimation etc, not sure if it fits your needs

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GMM.html

Disclaimer: used scikit, but never used GMM