# scipy.stats : multivariate_normal fitting?

Tags: python, scipy, normal-distribution, scipy.stats

I performed an analysis of data using MCMC method. This is an example of the result for only two parameters (n.b. : My model has 4 parameters) :

[image]

And I would like to do a multivariate fitting, but the `fit()`method seems to be not implemented for the `multivariate_normal` distribution in the `scipy.stats` package unlike the univariate distributions.
Which python package should I use to do that ?

Thanks for answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27230824/fit-multivariate-gaussian-distribution-to-a-given-dataset

Comment: @MaxPierini. It partially answers. It works with normal distributions but I am looking for a more generalist package for multivariate distributions. The `fit` method (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html) is only implemented for univariate distributions.

Answer (score 1):

[scipy/scipy#18986](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/18986) added a `fit` method to `scipy.stats.multivariate_normal` this summer. The feature will be available in SciPy 1.12.0, which is scheduled to be released around the end of the year. In the meantime, you can use the feature by [building from source](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/building/index.html) or using [nightly wheels](https://anaconda.org/scientific-python-nightly-wheels/scipy-openblas64). You can find the entry for `fit` in the [`multivariate_normal` documentation](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html) if you select "development" from the release dropdown menu.